# jquery hover inside a hover

Tags: jquery, hover

(at start sorry for my English)! 
I have a jquery hover problem.
I have a Navigation and if the mouse hover some element (player and login button) jquery show() the corresponding div. that work fine but when I hover the corresponding div the div hide but should stay.

Navigatin elements:

```
<li class="hover" title="login"><img src="images/nav-log.png" alt="player" border="0" /></li>       
<li class="hover" title="player"><img src="images/nav-ply.png" alt="player" border="0" /></li>
```

jquery:

```
var playerstat = 0;
$(".hover").mouseover(function() {


    link = $(this);
    layer = $("#" + link.attr("title") + "_content");   
    position = link.position();
    link.attr("id","aktiv");
    if(link.attr("title") == "player" && playerstat == 0){
        link.click(function() {

        });



    }

    layer.css({
        top : ($("html, body").scrollTop() + position.top + $(this).height() + 3) + 'px',
        left : (position.left - layer.outerWidth() + link.width()) + 'px'
    });

    layer.show();



    layer.mouseover(function() {
        alert("over");
        link.attr("id","aktiv");
        $(this).show();
        }).mouseleave(function(){
        link.attr("id","");
        $(this).hide();
    });
    }).mouseout(function(){
    link.attr("id","");   
    $("#" + $(this).attr("title") + "_content").hide();

});
```

the player:

```
  <div id="player_content" class="theme-gradient theme-shadow">
      <span id="track-info" class="theme-fontbggrey"></span> 
  <span id="player-layer"></span></div>
```

I hope somebody understand me... thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Write your "player_content" div into `<li class="hover" ...></li>` tags

Comment: like layer = $("#player_content"); ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you, 
You can do this

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("title") + "_content").bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
$(this).hide()
, $(this).show() 
});
```